# 2 divs overflow in Chrome but work fine in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, html

I am working on a webpage for a school project, nothing special. I have just about finished my site in IE, but when i try to open it in Chrome, its completely different, i would love some help if anyone has ideas.

__ *HTML* ____

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
  <head>
    <title>The Corner Shop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="realstyle.css" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
   </head>
  <body>
    <div id="menu1">
      <ul id="list-nav">
        <li>HOME</li>
        <li><a href="About us.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="Menu.html">THE MENU</a></li>
        <li><a href="Gallery.html">THE GALLERY</a></li>
        <li><a href="Contact details.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div> <!-- menu1 -->
    <div id="contentwrap">
      <div id="heading">
        <a href="index.html">
          <img border="0" src="GalleryI/Logo.jpg" width="170" height="150" alt="Logo" />
        </a>
      </div> <!-- heading -->
      <div id="content">
        <br />
        <br />
        <p id="texttitle">"The best burger joint around."</p>
        <p>Prepared and served with a passion.</p>
        <p id="textstuff">Using the freshest and best Australian ingredients, just for you.</p>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <p> This weeks special:</p>
        <br />
        <br />
        <img border= "5" src="GalleryI/beefburger.jpg" alt="Beef Burger Supreme" height="250" width="250" />
        <p>The Beef Burger Supreme $5.50</p>
      </div> <!-- content -->
    </div> <!-- contentwrap -->
  </body>
</html>
```

__ *CSS* ____

```
body {
  background-image: url("GalleryI/Background3.jpg");
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

a:link {
  color: White;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: White;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul#list-nav {
  margin:0;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  font-family: Impact, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform:uppercase !important;
  font-size: 20px;
  float:left;
  /* text-decoration: bold; */
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ul#list-nav li {
  display:inline;
  color:white;
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing:2px;
  line-height:35px;
  /* margin:right; */
  color:#CD2626;
  padding: 25px 25px 0px 30px;
}

ul#list-nav li a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#ffffff;
  /* float:left; */
}

ul#list-nav li a {
  text-align:center;
}

ul#list-nav li a:hover {
  color:#CD2626;
}

#menu1 ul {
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  background:#000000;
}

#heading {
  height: 150px;
  width: 780px;
  background-image: url("GalleryI/fast-food-burger1.jpg");
  color: white;
  padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
  text-align:left;
  margin:0 auto; 
  border: #000 5px solid;
}

#content {
  width: 800px;
  height: 650px;
  background-color: #090909;
  color: white;
  border-top: #000 5px solid;
  border-bottom: #000 5px solid;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align:center;
  font-family: arial,sans-serif;
  color: #CCC;
  margin:0 auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#contentmenu {
  width: 800px;
  height: 850px;
  background-color: #090909;
  color: white;
  border-top: #000 5px solid;
  border-bottom: #000 5px solid;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align:center;
  font-family: arial,sans-serif;
  color: #CCC;
  padding:20px 0px 5px 0px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#contentwrap {
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  opacity:0.9;
  filter:alpha(opacity=90);
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#texttitle {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  font-family: arial,sans-serif;
  font: italic bold;
}

#textstuff {
  font: arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#aboutuscontent {
  font: arial,sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 10px 50px 50px 50px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 40px;
}

#thing {
  color: red;
  font-size: 24px;
}

#thing2 {
  color: red;
  font-size: 24px;
}

#menutable {
  width: 700px;
  color: white;
  font-family: arial,sans-serif;
}
```

---

Some of this wont make sense because it is affecting the other pages that i didnt link, but basically the thing is, this works fine in IE, but the `menu1 div` is inside of my `contentwrap div` in Chrome, i don't know why this is happening. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Never, EVER use IE as a reference for how things should work. Inept at best, IE is the worst browser on the planet by far! Always, ALWAYS test your markup in a modern browser: ANYTHING but IE. Once your markup is working, THEN look to see how IE screws things up. But the multitude of problems with IE are well known, as are the hacks to fix it. The web developer's mantra: "If it works in IE, but not the other browsers, your markup is wrong!"

Comment: Gotcha, cheers for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I brought it your code up in Chrome and played around with it a little bit.

You can see what I did [here](http://jsfiddle.net/_andrewclarkson/T5tj3/embedded/result/)

It looks like there's a:

```
float: left;
```

in under your css rules for

```
ul#list-nav
```

I commented that out.

Just in case: if you wanted the elements *inside* it to float left try applying the rule to those. If you wanted it to overlap the wrapper try setting a z-index or applying the wrapper to float left as well.

Thanks much and Good Luck!

Comment: Thankyou for the fast reply, very nice spot, that fixed it fine. Problem solved, thanks alot :)

Comment: Ah ok i see where your coming from, ill keep that in mind incase i get stuck on this again. Thanks